# Laravel 4 render() PDF with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, dom, laravel-4

I need create a PDF from an HTML view rendering with Javascript Apis

This is my code in PHP Laravel 4

```
$con = Contrato::find($id);
        $html = (string) View::make('contratos.contratopdf')->with('con',$con)->render();
        return PDF::load(utf8_decode($html), 'A5', 'landscape')->show();
```

In the view I have this script

```
<script src="http://test.rentacar.cl/js/lib/jquery.signaturepad.min.js"></script>
```

This js change the Dom in a normal HTML but when I show in PDF don't work.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhantomJS works nicely, take a look at this package: https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs

Full documentation here: http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/

Example:

```
<?php

use JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client;

$client = Client::getInstance();

$request  = $client->getMessageFactory()->createCaptureRequest('http://google.com');
$response = $client->getMessageFactory()->createResponse();

$file = '/path/to/save/your/screen/capture/file.jpg';

$request->setCaptureFile($file);

$client->send($request, $response);
```

Comment: Could you provide a little more context as to how Phantom would be used, instead of just dumping a link to the tool?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a link to full documentation and a valid code example.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience of dompdf(very famous pdf library),those library don't support JS interpreting(because the php don't have the power to interpret the javascript),here are two workaound I think you can try.

1.Server side rendering html,move your dom manipulation to php in order to create the dom element.(Recommended)

2.Use php and phantomJS.The php call phantomJS to capture the screen of html and saved the screenshot to pdf.